# Streaming camera feed to server using javascript for mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, video-streaming, html5-video, opentok

We are working on a application which need to stream the video recording to server flow is as follow
1) Open a website start camera (primary)
2) start streaming of camera video to server
3) Finish

We are trying to use the opentok library, but there are many problems like session creation and server side storing the video

Please suggest the some other library for client and server side implementation or example to perform implement the same

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

OpenTok SDK is actually quite simple.

1. Create a session and token (aka a place for the video to stream to)
2. Connect to the session and publish video to the session
3. Start the archive (recording the session).

Sample code to create session and token and starting the archive (using Ruby):

```
require "opentok"
opentok = OpenTok::OpenTok.new api_key, api_secret
session = opentok.create_session :media_mode => :routed
token = session.generate_token
archive = opentok.archives.create session.session_id, :name => "Important Presentation"
```

Now that you have sessionId, token, and started recording for that session, all you have to do is stream video into the session. Here are some JS code:

```
var session = OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionId);

session.connect( data.token, function(err){
  if(!err){ session.publish(domId, properties); }
});
```

Its that simple!

Comment: Will it work with iPhone? any issue with browser compatibility?

Comment: iPhone browsers will not work because iPhone browsers does not support WebRTC. You have to use OpenTok Native SDK for iOS to build an iOS app: https://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/client/ios/. To try out archiving for iOS, download the OpenTokRTC app for iOS and then click on the record button on https://opentokrtc.com

Comment: Any other option for opentok